# Recognizing operand types from intel x86 syntax assembly

Tags: parsing, assembly, x86

I am working on a method to parse x86 intel syntax assembly code and generate abstract representation. Specifically, I am trying to understand how I can categorize an operand as one of these known x86 operand types : register, memory, constant/immediate operand, label (as descibed in http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/csbsju/cs/350/handouts/x86.html )

**For Example,**

Transform this snippet of **original assembly** :

```
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
push    -1
push    __ehhandler$_main
mov eax, DWORD PTR fs:0
```

into this snippet of **operand-abstracted assembly**:

```
push    register
mov register, register
push    constant
push    constant
mov register, memory
```

Any guidance on the complexity of this task, or pointers to tools that have related functionality is very much appreciated.

Comment: This looks just like simple instruction decoding. If a silly chip can do it, so can you?

Comment: Sounds like a simple assembly parser.  One observation, though: `__ehhandler$_main` is likely a symbol representing an address, and `push` is pushing that symbol's value (ie. it's `push constant` not `push memory`).

Comment: detecting operand types would be the most tedious task (but not difficult) here. it would make your life a lot simpler if you could parse assembly with at&t notation rather than intel.

Comment: I did not ask for code as the feedback from downvotes seemed to suggest. I gave an example of what I wanted to achieve, a link to a page from where I gained some understanding and hoped for pointers to where I can get additional information. While I did gain some understanding from the answers so far, I don't get why It is downvoted.

Comment: Ended up using distorm library to do this. Thanks for the useful responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can assemble the code, just disassemble it bk... the op-codes will tell you what type of operand(s) the instruction is dealing with.
Tomislav

Comment: The opcodes will tell the types for sure, was looking for a tool that could do that for me earlier. So I ended up finding one "distorm". thanks!